# Namespace interpolation in Less

Tags: less

Is it possible to use namespace interpolation in Less ?

```
 @color: "yellow";

 #top-yellow {
   .square(@param) {
     width: @param;
     height: @param;
   }
 }

 .example {
     #top-@color;                   // Use of #top-yellow namespace
     .square(10px);
 }
```

Thanks !

Comment: I thought `#top-@{color}` would work but it doesn't seem to. So I think this may not be possible.

Comment: Yes, and I don't understand why... Maybe namespace are loaded before variable interpretation. Do you know something like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parametric namespace instead (Notice namespaces and mixins are actually the same thing - i.e. the former is a purely logical abstraction).

```
@color: yellow;

 #top(yellow) {
     .square(@param) {
         width: @param;
         height: @param;
     }
 }

 .example {
     #top(@color); // use yellow #top namespace
     .square(10px);
 }
```